# What is the best way to write another text line starting with LPCTSTR?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to write another second line, but I don't know which code to use.

I've tried using \r\n, \n, \r, and etc,
but none of them worked.

Here is a part of my code.
(I included the header as well.)

```
HINSTANCE g_hInst;
LPCTSTR lpszClass = L"HelloAPI";
LPCTSTR ChildClassName  = L"ChildWin";


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);
LRESULT CALLBACK ChildWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR lpszCmdParam,
                     int nCmdShow)

    hWnd=CreateWindow(lpszClass,            
                    L"Visual C++",              
                    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,   
                    200, 200,                           
                    600, 600,                                           
                    (HWND)NULL,                         
                    (HMENU)NULL,                        
                    NULL);                              

       ShowWindow(hWnd,nCmdShow);
    
    while(GetMessage(&Message,0,0,0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&Message);
        DispatchMessage(&Message);
    }
    return Message.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT iMessage,
                         WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LPCTSTR text = L"Visual C++201934-243369";
    switch(iMessage) {
        case WM_PAINT:
            {
                PAINTSTRUCT ps;
                HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
                TextOut(hdc,100, 100, text, lstrlen(text));
                EndPaint(hWnd,&ps);
                return 0;
            }
```

Comment: you can follow this to add new line https://godbolt.org/z/g9lVhL

Comment: I removed some parts of the code since it says that I'm posting mostly only codes.

Comment: you can add the rest here and share the link again so I can compile. https://godbolt.org/z/SyqNu1

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/SyqNu1

Answer (score 1):

`TextOut` doesn't process linebreak characters in the input string.  Use [`DrawText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtext) instead, specifying the `DT_WORDBREAK` flag.